# Make panel background of a picture box VB

Tags: vb.net, panel

I am making a 1942 game in visual basic for my computer science final. I have everything working except for the background of my plane. The problem is that I have a very tall panel that fills the background of my form, and it reads the background of my form and not the panel. I want the background of my plane to match that of my panel. (I know this is a really bad explanation but I don't know how to explain it.)

[image]

Comment: If the PictureBox is parented to the Form, its *fake* background is taken from the form -- You should probably use a PictureBox as the background and draw a semi-transparent image (your airplane) on its surface.

Comment: Is there any way to do that vise-versa? Like make the panel the parent of the picture box?

Comment: Set the `Parent` property of the PB to your Panel reference. -- But, as mentioned, I suggest NOT to use a Panel as background. Use another PictureBox. Possibly - draw an image of the airplane over the background, instead of using a Control to hold your bitmap, you can have quite better results and rotate the image with ease, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This can get you close

```vb
Panel1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._1942

Dim image = My.Resources.plane
image.MakeTransparent(image.GetPixel(0, 0))

Dim pb = New PictureBox() With {.Image = image}
pb.Location = New Point(CInt(Panel1.Width / 2), CInt(Panel1.Height / 2))
pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent
pb.Parent = Panel1
```

[image]

But taking the top left pixel assumes the plane's background is all that same color. In your case, it is not! You can make this work by cleaning up all your "sprites" to have a flat backcolor. Better yet, don't sample the top corner, rather use some fixed color (I have seen magenta used: RGB(255, 0, 255)) so you don't rely on the top corner pixel being empty.

Comment: @liamcopeland did this help? I see this exact code used in [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70430054/832052) so it appears that it did.